# CSS ul is affected from another ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to create a menu which is divided into three parts:

- Left
- Middle
- Right

Then I did this:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QE7Yd/)

Now as you see, the left menu is affected from the middle menu, even though I did:

```
display:inline
```

I tried also to increase the *navgroups* class above then:

```
1000px
```

or alternatively to delete this line, but it doesn't change anything.

Thanks for helping!

## UPDATE:


In addition to what's written above, I wanted to try the middle-menu with an image instead of writing, then I just added this:

```
<img src="..">
```

but the image goes too down and I would like to put it more upper. 
Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks a lot for the supports, great forum!

Comment: float element left and right should stand first in html, then , content in tthe flow will stand aside/in middle, if enough room for it. litlle more about floats : http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Thanks! but also if I need to stand it in the line of the other menus, I should do <code>display:inline-block;</code>.
Thanks again!

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/QE7Yd/2/ ? or is it someting like display:flex;justify-content:space-between; ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nrbDl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still having trouble with centering, you can simply add another container around the `.navgroups` div.

Here's the CSS with fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QE7Yd/4/

```
.navwrap {
    text-align:center;
}

.navgroups {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#CC0000;
}

.navgroups:before,
.navgroups:after {
    display:table;
    content:'';
    clear:both;
}

.navgroups li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}
.navgroups .menuleft {
    padding:0px;
    float: left;
}
.navgroups .menumiddle {
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}
.navgroups .menuright {
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

Basically you are telling the `.navgroups` to be treated like and `inline` element and using the `.navwrap` to say the text inside should be centered.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted that would be. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it's what you needed. If this answers your question, then can you mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: I don't have this option yet. My reputation is too low. 
But also, if you can see, I updated the question and I would like to hear your advise. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should float them all left, if you want them to all line up horizontally. Here's an  [update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QE7Yd/6/) to demonstrate.
    ...

```
.navgroups {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
.navgroups li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}
.navgroups .menuleft {
    padding:0px;
    float: left;
}
.navgroups .menumiddle {
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.navgroups .menuright {
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
}
```

**UPDATE:** To accommodate the image you mention in your update, you could add a `line-height` on the text equal to the image height. I'm not sure exactly how you want them lined up, but that will let you adjust it. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QE7Yd/7/

Comment: But the menu is not aligned to center, the margin:0 auto; does not work.

Comment: You won't be able to use `margin:0 auto` like that because the `.navgroups` div doesn't have a specified width to work with. There is a work around...see my answer.

Comment: just add `display: table;` to .navgroups and it will be centered. I updated the fiddle.

Comment: @rolory, I added a comment and new fiddle to address the image question in your update.

Comment: It's weird, the image's width is grown if I change the image's height which makes my image go lower.
Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The ul (like divs) comes automatically with a display: block on it, meaning that it will take up the entire width of whatever container it is in.  Were it me, I would make three containing divs for the uls which would handle the floating. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2Lt2/) to help explain.  All of the divs have a float left as I've never found it useful to mix different types of floats in that purpose.

```
.navgroups {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navgroups .menuleft {
    padding:0px;
    float: left;
}
.navgroups .menuright {
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}
.navgroups .menumiddle {
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also, to remove the bullet points from the ul, add this to your css, which will prevent the images from moving down.

```
.navgroups li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: As I said to Brian Stephens, the menu isn't aligned to center (the margin:0 auto; doesn't work).
GCyrillus already helped me but I have another problem. If I put an image instead of "TEXT", the image goes down, like it has clear:both.
Its size is adjusted to the distance between menuleft and menuright but It still goes lower.

Comment: Update your question above if you have having difficulty with something else.

Comment: I don't think you can align a ul to center, you'll have to use containing divs with margin:0 auto; to do that.  I'm also not sure what you mean by the image moving down.  Do you mean it's being moved down by the bullet? EDIT @rolory if that was the case, I updated my answer.  I can provide another fiddle if that's the case.